# Linking accounts with google assistant returns "Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange"

Tags: c#, actions-on-google

Trying to link a demo account to my google assistant service keeps throwing me "Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange" when I redirect to the redirect url specified by google. I'm using MVC with C# on my side.

My flow follows the code here

```
public ActionResult Authorize(OAuthRequest request)
{

    ViewBag.Message = "Authorize Google to access your account?";
    User user = GetUserData();

    ViewBag.User = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.UserName) ? user.UserName : null;
    Session["OAuth"] = request;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult LinkAccount(bool confirmation)
{
    if (Session["OAuth"] == null || !ValidateGoogleRequest((OAuthRequest)Session["OAuth"]))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    if (!confirmation)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        OAuthRequest request = (OAuthRequest)Session["OAuth"];

        User user = GetUserData();

        string accessCode = Token.CreateAccessCode(user.UserName);
        string url = $"{request.Redirect_URI}?code={accessCode}&state={request.State}";

        return Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

The OAuthRequest is just an object that stores all the parameters google passes.

```
public class OAuthRequest
{
    public string Client_ID { get; set; }
    public string Redirect_URI { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public string Response_Type { get; set; }
}
```

I am using https on localhost for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this code had no issues. The reason for the “Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange” response was due to the fact that Google's handler was unable to look up the DNS for my Token exchange API.